# What's the best way to instantiate a generic from its name?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, reflection, .net-2.0

Assuming I have only the class name of a generic as a string in the form of "MyCustomGenericCollection(of MyCustomObjectClass)" and don't know the assembly it comes from, what is the easiest way to create an instance of that object?

If it helps, I know that the class implements IMyCustomInterface and is from an assembly loaded into the current AppDomain.

Markus Olsson gave an excellent example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238/c-instantiating-classes-from-xml), but I don't see how to apply it to generics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you parse it up, use [Type.GetType(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) to get a reference to the types involved, then use [Type.MakeGenericType(Type[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) to construct the specific generic type you need.  Then, use [Type.GetConstructor(Type[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) to get a reference to a constructor for the specific generic type, and finally call [ConstructorInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17.aspx) to get an instance of the object.

```
Type t1 = Type.GetType("MyCustomGenericCollection");
Type t2 = Type.GetType("MyCustomObjectClass");
Type t3 = t1.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { t2 });
ConstructorInfo ci = t3.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object obj = ci.Invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN article [How to: Examine and Instantiate Generic Types with Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx) describes how you can use Reflection to create an instance of a generic Type. Using that in conjunction with Marksus's sample should hopefully get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind translating to VB.NET, something like this should work

```
foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    // find the type of the item
    Type itemType = assembly.GetType("MyCustomObjectClass", false);
    // if we didnt find it, go to the next assembly
    if (itemType == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Now create a generic type for the collection
    Type colType = assembly.GetType("MyCusomgGenericCollection").MakeGenericType(itemType);;

    IMyCustomInterface result = (IMyCustomInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(colType);
    break;
}
```