# Obtain Control type from string c#

Tags: c#, types

I have a String like this:

```
typeStr = label1.GetType().ToString();
```

Now I want to reversely get the `type` of this control by `typeStr`.

I try some function like `Type.GetType(typeStr)` but does not help.

Is there any simple way to obtain the `type`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Why do you need a string representation of a type name and why do you need to parse it back to a `Type` object?

Comment: What exception when you tried `GetType`?

Comment: Related or maybe dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702916/is-there-a-typeof-inverse-operation

Comment: I want to Serislize a class whith som attributes. my class has an attribute: Type elementType, but type Type can not be serializes. I had to use type String instead of Type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to Type c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `Type` Fullname

```
Type type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Label");
```

This will create the type and to create the instance of object u can use `Activator.CreateInstance`

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

---

### Working with `Type` loaded in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`

```
   private void btnAddDymanicLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Type type = GetTypeNameFromDomain("System.Windows.Forms.Label");
        Label lbl = (Label) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        lbl.Text = "dynamic created control";


    }

    private Type GetTypeNameFromDomain(string typename)
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.FullName == typename)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

A simple example :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    int num = (int) obj;
    num = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(num); // prints : 10
}
```

Comment: this answer is complete Thanks a lot,my problem is solved! Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the name with

```
typeStr = label1.GetType().GetFullName();
```

Then

```
type = Type.GetType(typeStr);
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked.  He asked "is there any way to get `Type` of a string represantation of it?". And there is no `GetFullName()` method of `GetType()`. I assume you want to use `FullName` property.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to get and instance of that type only from a string like this

```
classname instance = Activator.CreateInstance("<assemblyname>","<classname>") as classname;
```