# How to call generic method if I have only Type instance?

Tags: .net, generics

```
class A
{
    public static void M<T>() { ... }
}

...
Type type = GetSomeType();
```

Then I need to call `A.M<T>()` where `type == typeof(T)`.
Reflection?

Comment: Yes, this is only possible using reflection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to instantiate a generic from its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130208/whats-the-best-way-to-instantiate-a-generic-from-its-name)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need reflection. For example:

```
var method = typeof(A).GetMethod("M");
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
generic.Invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the type is known at runtime you need to use reflection:

```
Type type = GetSomeType();
var m = typeof(A)
    .GetMethod("M", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .MakeGenericMethod(type);
m.Invoke(null, null);
```