# Generic type classes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an extension method that registers some services :

```
endpoints.MapService<MyService>();
```

Behind the scenes the extension method looks like:

```
public static void MapService<TService>(this IEndpointRouteBuilder builder) where TService : class
```

Now I don't have the actual classes to configure at runtime but I do have the Type of the class which is `typeof(MyService)`, how can I use that to register my service using the extension method `MapService`?
I am guessing some methods in the reflection namespace could help me with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call generic method if I have only Type instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805814/how-to-call-generic-method-if-i-have-only-type-instance)

Comment: What does the method actually do? Some IoC frameworks have overloads that take type-objects as parameters, with a generic overload for convenience.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve, I think that you want to do something like swagger???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to retrieve the generic definition of the `MapService` function and then make a generic method out of it using [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=net-5.0), like so:

```
// This needs to be the type which contains "MapService".
Type typeWhereMapServiceIs = typeof(ServiceExtensionMethods);

MethodInfo mapServiceMethod = typeWhereMapServiceIs.GetMethod("MapService", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

MethodInfo mapServiceMyService = mapServiceMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyService));

mapServiceMyService.Invoke(null, new object[] { builder });
```